# Bootstrap Modal with scroolbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I just upgraded **Bootstrap** from **2.x to 3.x** and found that `modal` dialog(http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) do not have vertical scroll bar anymore for large content body. How to set modal body max height and enable scroll bar?

Answer (score 2):

You can set a height and enable the scrollbar using:

```
#myModal .modal-content
{
  height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

If you don't want the scroll bar on the entire modal, use `modal-body` instead:

```
#myModal .modal-body
{
  height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/88983

Comment: Hi Skelyy! Don't you know how to reset a scroll position on second opening the modal, if before closing you scrolled down?